# How is spectator interference handled in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball, officiating, nba

I'm wondering how the NBA handles spectator interference. As an example, during a free throw, what if the audience screams "BRICK" as they shoot, or someone pulls down their pants behind the hoop, etc..

My main concern is that any rule can be abused in both ways.

1. It can legitimately distract the player
2. It can be used by any player as an excuse to gain an advantage

There's nothing stopping teams/people from paying audience members a few bucks to be a nuisance, and everyone can utilize this. So my questions are

1. How exactly is this dealt with, according to the rules?
2. Has this every been abused (similar to how I described)?

Comment: "There's nothing stopping teams [...] from paying audience members a few bucks to be a nuisance" If the league found out about this (and they almost certainly would), they would drop a ton of bricks on the team's head. It doesn't matter if it's explicitly in the rule book or not, it comes under the generic "bringing the game into disrepute" statutes where the league has enormous discretion.

Comment: "if not, why not" is not answerable (we'd have to know every spectator's motivations for the history of the NBA...)